# I don't understand why it says so "Integer expression expected"

Tags: bash, shell

So here is my code

```
#!bin/bash

PS3='Pick the one you like and we will continue: '

select color in "Blue" "Black" "Orange" "Yellow"
do
echo "You selected $color"
break
done

echo

var=":"

echo "Alrighty, please type in the password as you have specified the    color $color"

read var

until  [ "$var" -ne password ] 
do
echo "You have specified a wrong password, and a wrong color please leave the script the script"
break
done
```

Terminal responce is as follow:

```
1) Blue
2) Black
3) Orange
4) Yellow
Pick the one you like and we will continue: 1
You selected Blue

Alrighty, please type in the password as you have specified the color Blue
23
/root/Desktop/Bash/Test_1.sh: line 16: [: password: integer expression  expected
You have specified a wrong password, and a wrong color please leave the script
```

Comment: Dot forget to accept the answer that helped you!

Answer (score 2):

You are doing:

```
[ "$var" -ne password ]
```

`-ne` (not equal) is an integer operator of `[` i.e. it expects integers on both sides.

But you have `var=":"` at start and although you are `read`-ing user input and put that in `var`, presumably the input is not an integer, leading to the error message.

*In any case, if it were an integer the check would fail because, `password` is a string itself to begin with.*

If you want to compare strings for equality, the operator is `=`:

```
[ "$var" = password ]
```

Non-equality:

```
[ "$var" != password ]
```

Comment: Alright so here is what I did

instead of :

    var=":"

I did:

    var=notset

And for the until statment I did:
    
until [ ! "$var" = password ]

Now the terminal doesn't give the error but it closes itself after I type in the value of read var

Comment: Nevermine I figured it out, thanks for the help @heemayl

Comment: For Perl scripters, I will note that this is the opposite of Perl comparison operators, where -ne is for string comparison.